# slider argument

Tags: google-earth-engine

in the follow code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b236b0231fe567f816976a8a6bc20283

```js
// Use a DateSlider to create annual composites of this collection.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1');
// Use the start of the collection and now to bound the slider.
var start = ee.Image(collection.first()).date().get('year').format();
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).format();

// Run this function on a change of the dateSlider.
var showMosaic = function(range) {
  var mosaic = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
    collection: collection.filterDate(range.start(), range.end())
  });
  // Asynchronously compute the name of the composite.  Display it.
  range.start().get('year').evaluate(function(name) {
    var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 100};
    var layer = ui.Map.Layer(mosaic, visParams, name + ' composite');
    Map.layers().set(0, layer);
  });
};

// Asynchronously compute the date range and show the slider.
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, end).evaluate(function(range) {
  var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: range['dates'][0],
    end: range['dates'][1],
    value: null,
    period: 365,
    onChange: showMosaic,
    style: {width: '180px'}
  });
  Map.add(dateSlider.setValue(now));
});

// Initialize the map location at southern Africa.
Map.setCenter(23.861, -27.144, 6);
```

I'm wondering about the argument `range` here:
[image]

With here:

[image]

Whether it is the same?

If they are the same, how do you pass the date of the current slider to the showMosaic function?